# Bootstrap modal showing on one page and not another

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I have two pages which I believe are identical on one bootstrap modal is appearing. Scroll to venn diagram on each page. Right click the image and a modal should appear.

1. [stakeholder salience](http://www.stakeholdermap.com/stakeholder-analysis/stakeholder-salience.html) modal doesn't appear.
2. [second page](http://www.stakeholdermap.com/stakeholder-analysis/1-stakeholder-salience.html) modal does appear

I need to work out why the modal is not appear on the 1st page.

Comment: Show some code in the question

Comment: modal is triggered by  <div class="embed" data-target="#embed1">. First part of modal code is   <div id="embed1" class="modal fade"....

Comment: <!-- Modal on right click-->
        <script>
   $(".embed").on("contextmenu", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
    //$("#embed1").modal("show");
    var targetModal = $(this).data('target');
  $(targetModal).modal("show");
})
</script>

Comment: The modal works on one page and not on the other.

Answer (score 0):

SumoMe Highlighter is blocking the modal. On the first page an on page highlight is present. On the second page there are no highlights. Turning off SumoMe Highlighter resolves the problem and the modal is shown correctly.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14012250)

Comment: Sure, but this does answer the question. The behaviour was cased by SumoMe Highlighter.